# flipflop activity of button in android

Tags: android

### I have searched many place & posted questions in stackoverflow for a requirement below

[image]

Click on `button` ..... `1` should display ...... Click on the `button` again `2` should display.... click on the `button` again `1` should display again !

---

**This cycle should keep continuing**

*I have ony got recomendations for using tabhost and use tabs .... i am not looking for where we use different tabs to launch different activities ....*

**Any Ideas !**

***An example would certainly help***

Comment: use a viewflipper widget to switch between your different views.

Answer (score 1):

Activities are not designed for this, they represent a screen and not a portion of a screen. As such, they cannot be included in another screen, what you are looking for are [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) You'll need to move your code from Activity to Fragment, it's a pretty easy refactoring once you understand the lifecycle of Fragment inside an Activity.

As for the screen switching, as simple boolean value keeping track of which Fragment is being displayed should do, replacing the Fragment in view using something like this :

```
boolean fragmentOneDisplayed = true;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment newFragment = fragmentOneDisplayed ? new Fragment2() : new Fragment1();
    ft.replace(id of Fragment's placeholder in your Activity's layout , new Fragment);
    ft.commit();
    fragmentOneDisplayed = (newFragment instanceof Fragment1) ? true : false;
}
});
```